# <apex:iframe> X-Frame-Options issue?

Tags: iframe

My requirement is to embed a report into a Custom visualforce page. For this I am using apex:iframe with 'src'  parameter value set as relative url to the Report. However it does not give any error at compile time but at runtime it only displays a blank page. When I used firebug to inspect it shows 
**"Refused to display 'https://....' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."**

Does anybody know solution for this problem? Or it will be really helpful if anybody provides alternate way to embed reports into visualforce page.

VisualForce page is:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:iframe src="/00OW0000000FngF" scrolling="true"/>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks,
KP

Comment: Can you post your code? The VF page and the report should have the same origin so you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: @BarCotter  My visualforce page has following content:
<apex:page>  <apex:iframe src='/reportId' scrolling='true'>  </apex:iframe   </apex:page>

Comment: That is not a valid page. The iframe tag is not properly closed and you are hard coding the report URL to `'/reportId'` rather than `'/' + {!reportId}` (assuming you have a variable called `reportId` in the controller)

Comment: Thanks BarCotter!  Updated Code is :-
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:iframe src="/00OW0000000FngF" scrolling="true"/>
</apex:page>

Comment: I have added that code to your question

Comment: Thanks for your help however updated code is not resolving the issue. Still getting blank page with same error in Developer Console. Do you know any other workaround for embedding reports in VF page?

Comment: I didnt think those changes would of been the fix (sorry should of mentioned that) but now there is enough info in your question for other people to help and also try reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

SalesForce stopped supporting the displaying of reports in iFrames in Spring '14. They also introduced the [Reporting API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf) in this release. Try using the [analytics:reportChart](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) tag to display your report. Example:

```
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OZ0000000I3rc"/>
```

Comment: [Here](http://peterknolle.com/apex-analytics-api-and-report-chart-component/) is a code example on displaying reports